# Merge all dataframe csv files into one

Tags: r, csv, import

Using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433532/10434919).

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

As the next step with a simple line, how is it possible to merge all read csv files/dataframes into one?

We suppose that all dataframes have the same column names.

Comment: One of the [answers on that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40943207/5325862) uses `purrr::map_df`, which calls `bind_rows` across all data frames and returns a single data frame, I'm assuming how you want (can't say for sure without a [reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this question on stackoverflow a while ago:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
datalist = lapply(files, function(x)read.csv(x)) 
df = do.call("rbind", datalist)
```

Comment: If all you are doing is cutting and pasting another Stack Overflow answer, then you would do better to just mark the question duplicate and move on :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(files, read_csv)
```